# ruby gem install issue - ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'vim-ruby' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby

I typed following command in prompt:

```
# gem install vim-ruby --remote
```

then got a error message:

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'vim-ruby' (>= 0) in any repository

My environment is windows xp and ruby's version is 1.9.3
how to solve it?

Comment: I don't think `vim-ruby` is a gem to be installed, rather a [collection of `vim` files](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) that are useful to `vim`.

Answer (score 2):

[vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) is not a gem. Checking the gem repository using `gem list vim -r` returns several gems, but not that one.

From the docs:

How you get these files into Vim:

[...]

- By downloading one of the tarballs, you can easily install the latest
  stable or development version wherever you like on your machine.  No
  README, no vim-ruby-install.rb, just Vim files.  You would typically
  install these into either $VIM/vimfiles, for system-wide use, or $HOME/.vim
  ($HOME/vimfiles on Windows) for personal use.
- Remember that when you install Vim in the first place, all of these files
  are present.  The purpose of downloading and installing them from
  github is to get the latest version of them.

Answer (score 1):

vim-ruby is not a gem but the page: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby has a link https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki in which the link "VimRubySupport" has a section "Installing the latest version" which shows the vim-ruby as a gem. I too had the same problem as the original post. I downloaded the archive file from http://rubyforge.org/projects/vim-ruby/ which has a .rb file (bin/vim-ruby-install.rb after untarring the archive in my case) which installs the required vim files.

Answer (score 1):

This [method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203632/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository/204022#204022) should solve your issue:

```
$ gem install --http-proxy http://201.187.107.19:8080 vim-ruby
```

Note, the IP address and the port number refers to a proxy. You should search for a proxy list and use one of the proxies there.

This is sample site with proxies: http://www.cybersyndrome.net/pla5.html