# Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Does anybody else spend more time wrestling with rails than actually coding with it??

Very new to rails and programming in general, so I apologize if this is a stupidly easy question. I don't know enough to understand what's wrong here.

I upgraded to ruby 2.2.2 and somehow lost rails in the process. I don't know why. Now every time I try to load it again, I get the following:

```
 Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I've tried `sudo gem install rails` and `gem install rails` to the same effect. I've already checked similar postings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835830/error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664596/ruby-gem-install-issue-error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-vim-ruby-0-in), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762802/error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-2-12-3-0-in-any-repository), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424703/ruby-on-rails-error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repositor), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492110/error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository) to no effect.

How can I fix this and move on?

Macbook pro 10.10.3
Ruby 2.2.2

`Chases-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting Chase$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
Chases-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting Chase$ gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
Chases-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting Chase$ bundle install
-bash: bundle: command not found
Chases-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting Chase$`

**edit**

I'm behind a VPN, but that shouldn't make a difference because I've checked this several times and it has never been a problem for coding in the past. Since I live in China I have to use VPN a lot, but most of the coding sites are open.

**Right now I'm systematically going through each solution and copying down the error messages.**

Here's what happened when I did everything at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835830/error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository)

[ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835830/error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository/11837422#11837422)

1) railsinstaller.org = the packages are out of date. Nothing over 10.6. Does that matter?

2)`where ruby?` = `-bash where: command not found`

3)`rvm gem install rails` = `Please note that`rvm gem ...`was removed, try`gem install rails`or`rvm all do gem install rails`instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )`

4) `gem install rails = could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository.`

5) `rvm all do gem install rails`
= nothing. It just sat there and didn't seem to do anything.

6) curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled [--ruby] [--rails] [--trace] 
= A bunch of information but no action. I opened to new terminal window 10 minutes ago and it still hasn't done anything.

7) `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails` 
= installs rvm and then ends with the same error `could not find a valid gem for rails`

8) `gem sources -a https://rubygems.org` = added the site to the sources... idk if that will change anything...

**no change after following all the previous steps**

Since I know rails is not on my computer and something might have changed since I did the steps above, I just set my VPN to a new setting and used  `sudo gem install rails`. This appears to have installed rails and many gems, however...

I then ran `rails -v` and got the following error:

`[!] There was an error parsing`Gemfile`: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot - gem 'rails', 3.2.11
                 ^
/Users/Chase/Desktop/pinteresting/Gemfile:4: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('. Bundler cannot continue.`

`#  from /Users/Chase/Desktop/pinteresting/Gemfile:4
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #`

> gem 'rails', 3.2.11
>    #  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
>    #  -------------------------------------------`

Comment: Will you please show your full error log?

Comment: Are you using RVM or another ruby version manager?

Comment: I'm using RVM. Just added the error log.

Comment: What does $rails -v return?  Doe the return value match with the version specified in the gemfile?

Comment: `gem list rails --remote` should display a bunch of gems on a well installed rvm. If it doesn't, you will have to find how to configure rvm to access rubygems.

Comment: Rails -v returns "not currently installed in the system." It then tells me to `sudo gem install rails`, which returns `cannot find a valid gem`...

Comment: `gem list rails --remote` returned only this: `*** REMOTE GEMS ***` ... what does that mean?

Comment: Did you try adding a version like "gem install rails -v 4.2.1"

Comment: Yes. It still says could not find a valid gem rails.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same problem as follows:

> gem source -a http://rubygems.org/

I think the reason is about https.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the steps I listed earlier, I connected to VPN through a new setting. The one I was using only routed the VPN through my browser, but the new one affects the entire internet connection. I think this is what finally allowed me to download rails again.

After downloading rails, it was just a matter of messing with the Gemfile to get everything downloaded, and voila!

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this after trying all the solutions on the Internet for hours by just connecting through my phone.